# How do I call a nested navigation graph outside the main navigation graph in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to organise my project so that it has nested graphs and currently I have 2 nested graphs: AuthenticationGraph and BottomBarGraph. The problem is that when I am in the home screen (which is the start destination of BottomBarGraph), I declare scaffold that has a bottom bar and I need to call the graph for this bottom bar.

BottomBarNavGraph.kt

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.bottomBarNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
){
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screens.HomeScreen.route,
        route = BOTTOM_BAR_ROUTE
    ){
        composable(
            route = Screens.HomeScreen.route
        ){
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

HomeScreen.kt

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController)}
    ) {

    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavHostController){
    val screens = listOf(
        BottomBarScreen.Home,
        BottomBarScreen.Profile,
        BottomBarScreen.Settings
    )

    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    
    BottomNavigation {
        screens.forEach { screen->
            AddItem(
                screen = screen,
                currentDestination = currentDestination,
                navController = navController )
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this cause the nested graph is declared as a NavGraphBuilder. I would like to keep the nested graphs and be able to do this without separating them